# Applescript creation date

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to make an Automator service that does the following:

- Input is selected files
- Create new folder and copy selected files
- HELP* Applescript to get creation date/time and filter out any files made more than a minute ago (a variable called input[contains
  image path] is passed to this script)
- Rename files
- Resize files

I have everything working except step three, which is important because if the service is run a second time in the same folder the already resized files will be resized a second time. In order to work around this I want to create an Applescript that filters out anything that was create more than 40 second/1 minute ago.

So far I have this, and it's returning an error:

```
on run {input, parameters}


set theFileDate to (creation date of input as string)
display dialog theFileDate

return input
end run
```

I'm trying to display dialog so that I can verify the code is working and see the format for the date/time

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Finder's scripting dictionary to access the creation date property.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set theFileDate to (creation date of input as string)
    end tell
    display dialog theFileDate
    return input
end run
```

Comment: No I tried your script in a workflow.  It didn't work.  The parameter called "input" is a list.  You would need a loop (see my answer below).  Also, converting the date to a string is OK to display it, to compare dates, you wouldn't  want a date as string, you would want some kind of date or number to compare using a relational operator such as "is greater than" or ">" or some such thing.

Comment: @Kaydell My point was you need to wrap the line in a `tell application "Finder"` block, to get the date, which was the only thing he was actually having trouble retrieving. I simply wrote it that way to prove that it would output a proper date - I wasn't intending to write the entire script for him.

Comment: I don't think that your code runs.  1. input is a list, so you do need a loop. 2. to get the creation date, I believe that you need to do "get info for" on a single file.  Did you try to get your code to run?  I couldn't get it to run.  Here is how I *can* get the date of a file: "get creation date of (info for (choose file))"

Comment: @Kaydell `input` can be anything if it's an automator action. If it's multiple files, yes, you would need to loop over each file. Besides that, it does run standalone (by that I mean not inside a `on run` block). Run this in AppleScript Editor if you don't believe me. http://d.chend.me/SM5z

Comment: "input can be anything if it's an automator action." OK, I realize this, but when I setup an Automator action to process files and folders, I restrict the Service to only accept selected files and folders from the Finder or I setup the first action to be "Get Selected Finder Items", then I know what my workflow is going to get.  I wouldn't want the end user to get a mysterious error message by letting them select anything, let's say a word, and then running my Service.  Each part of the software the you develop has its pre conditions and post conditions.

Comment: "Run this in AppleScript Editor if you don't believe me."  OK, that worked.  I just learned something and that is outside of a Finder's tell-block, you have to use something like the following: "get creation date of (info for (choose file))" but inside of a Finder's tell-block, your code, this part of it: http://d.chend.me/SM5z does work

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your code.  I believe that this is closer.

```
-- This script will (when completed) filter the list of Finder items in the input parameter
-- returning as an output only those files that meet the specified criteria.
on run {input, parameters}
    -- if no items were selected, tell the user and cancel the workflow
    if ((count of input) < 1) then
        display alert "This workflow will do nothing because no items were selected in the Finder"
        set CANCEL_WORKFLOW to -128
        error CANCEL_WORKFLOW
    end if
    -- select the items to be output by this action
    set output to {}
    repeat with thisItem in input
        -- display the thisItem's path name and creation date
        display dialog (thisItem as text)
        set theFileDate to (creation date of (get info for thisItem))
        display dialog theFileDate as text
        ------ replace the next line of code with a compare of theFileDate to current date -----
        set addThisItem to true
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- add items that meet the criteria to the output (which is a list)
        if addThisItem then
            set output to output & thisItem
        end if
    end repeat
    -- return the output of this action to be the input of the next action
    return output
end run
```

Let me know how this goes.

-- Kaydell
[kaydell@yahoo.com](http://mailto%3akaydell@yahoo.com)
http://learnbymac.com

Answer (score 0):

Or.

You simply set the label index colour when the files have been processed. And filter for ones that are not the labeled colour.

Here in this example I filter out items with the label index **Purple**

And colour processed items purple which are then ignored on the second run.

[image]

Comment: I don't want add label colors as that would cause a lot of confusion, though I am already trying to just filter out items that contain "- Resized", as I am already adding this at the end of the work flow. you can almost do this with just the automator filter, but you can filter by "does not contain", which is what I need. 

I started a new question because I was stuck on this new filter task. Though now I see I should have just posted it here. Sorry, I'm new here.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910790/applescript-finder-path-into-posix-path[link]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note that you can change "60" to "40" or any other amount of seconds needed.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set filterDate to (current date) - 60
    set filteredFiles to {}

    repeat with i from 1 to count of input
        set thisFile to item i of input
        if (class of thisFile) is text then set thisFile to thisFile as alias
        set creationDate to (creation date of (get info for thisFile))
        if creationDate is greater than or equal to filterDate then
            set end of filteredFiles to (item i of input)
        end if
    end repeat

    return filteredFiles
end run
```