# Applescript Finder path into POSIX path

Tags: path, applescript, finder

I'm running the following applescript:

```
tell application "Finder"
set input to POSIX file "/Users/sam/Desktop/Resized"
set theFiles to (every file of folder input whose name does not contain "- Resized")
end tell

return theFiles
```

It's working as it should, though it's returning:

```
{document file "HighResCat.jpg" of folder "Resized" of folder "Desktop" of folder "sam" of    folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder", document file "madonna.jpg" of folder "Resized" of folder "Desktop" of folder "sam" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder"}
```

where I need a POSIX path (/Users/sam/Desktop/Resized/HighResCat.jpg) to pass to automator

++++++++++++ EDIT

I've got it this far, but I can only pass one item of the list at a time when I need all of the items.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set input to POSIX file "/Users/sam/Desktop/Resized"
    set theFiles to (every file of folder input whose name does not contain "-  Resized")
set input to item 1 of theFiles as string
end tell


return (POSIX file input)
```

I converted to a string and on return converted to POSIX

+++++++++EDIT2

This script worked inside automator:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set input to (input) as string
tell application "System Events" to set theFiles to POSIX path of (files of folder    input whose name does not contain "- Resized")
set input to theFiles
return input
end run
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set input to "/Users/sam/Desktop/Resized"
tell application "System Events" to set theFiles to POSIX path of (files of folder input whose name does not contain "- Resized")
return theFiles
```

Comment: `Result:
error "System Events got an error: Can’t make file \"Macintosh HD:Users:sam:Desktop:Resized\" into type integer." number -1700 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:sam:Desktop:Resized" to integer`

Comment: Everytime I try to convert the path to POSIX is says that it can't convert "path" to integer.

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly `set input to "/Users/sam/Desktop/Resized"` or did you use `set input to POSIX file "/Users/sam/Desktop/Resized"` ?